# Flutter checksum Crc16Xmodem of crclib does not return expected value

Tags: flutter, dart, checksum

In my Flutter project, I tried to get a checksum for the string '00020101021230480016A00000067701011201150105523009350080205012095802TH62200716SCOSM800129099915303764540510.006304' to make a payment QR code.
The intended checksum string should be 0x0000AAC1 and should be a string type.
I tried below lib but failed to get the result.

> crclib: ^3.0.0

Neither of The following two lines could return the expected value.

```
String cdata='00020101021230480016A00000067701011201150105523009350080205012095802TH62200716SCOSM800129099915303764540510.006304';
Crc16Xmodem().convert(utf8.encode(cdata)).toString(); // returns 46184
Crc16Xmodem().convert(utf8.encode(cdata)).toRadixString(16); // returns b468
```

Please help me, thank you.

need the desired string value 0x0000AAC1 from Crc16Xmodem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the desired output is `AAC1`, you should be using the `CRC-16/CCITT-FALSE` algorithm, not `Crc16Xmodem`.

Remember that you need to pad the output too if you want it on the `0x0000xxxx` format.

```dart
String cdata = '00020101021230480016A00000067701011201150105523009350080205012095802TH62200716SCOSM800129099915303764540510.006304';
final crc = Crc16CcittFalse().convert(utf8.encode(cdata));
final crcString = '0x${crc.toRadixString(16).padLeft(8, '0')}';
print(crcString);
// 0x0000AAC1
```

Comment: Thank you spydon. Your code works perfectly.

Comment: @FlutterWow glad it worked, it can be quite tricky to find the correct CRC algorithm to use.